# Make calculated column from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to make a calculated columns from different tabel, i want to calculate TotalPrice from table A, which is from Quantity on Table B, and UnitPrice on Table C.

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Add example data and expected output

Comment: **Computed columns** (that are defined as part of a given table) cannot depend on other tables - only columns from the table in question, expressions and static values

Answer (score 0):

Like @marc_s explain you, you can create computed only with column of the same table. If you want a "table" with a calcul between multiple table you can create simply a view.

[Create view on SQL SERVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms187956.aspx)